# Wall height calculation for the mono pitch roof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I am trying to find out the height of the wall for my poly-tunnel construction.
Can you please let me know what the height of the the wall will be?
[image]

**Update**

Maybe the image below is the correct one. I want a lean-to roof with 15 degrees.

[image]

***Update***

I made some more research and I think the below image is what i want.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don`t know where to start

Comment: Are you sure that that angle is $15^\circ$? Because that would make the opposite wall have negative height.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I am sure. What do you mean negative height? It will certainly be less than 4 meters.

Comment: I mean it will be below ground. If the angle is $75^\circ$, on the other hand...

Comment: Taking to acount your picture the height would be $4-10\cos 15º<0$.

Comment: Maybe I put the angle at the wrong place. Maybe 15 degrees should go to the other wall...

Comment: I have updated my question and added another image

Comment: You'd better study some trig rules, instead of asking here.

Comment: @Aretino it has been a very long time since I left school. I think i am too old to study...

Comment: Read here: http://www.mathopenref.com/trigtangent.html

Comment: @Aretino According to that my short side should be 1.32 meters. But that is too short. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let's make $DE \perp AE$. Then:

$$\tan 75°=\frac{DE}{AE}=\frac{10}{AE}=\tan(45°+30º)=\frac{\tan45°+\tan 30°}{1-\tan45°\cdot\tan 30°}$$

Now you can find $AE$ and then:

$$CD=BE=4-AE$$

Can you finish?

Comment: @baris: is it clear?